# Integrating Firebase push notification in ionic 3 for website platform

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, angularfire2

I am working in ionic 3 app .

I want **push notificatio**n into my app . I have tried to do it with code push 
but I can see that it only support Android and iOS.

So I want to integrate push notification WITH FIREBASE in my ionic app (version 3) , **for web platform**

So far I have not got any tutorial or any video on internet where push notification is integrated via firebse **for web platform**
  **is it possible to integrate firebse push notification in ionic 3 app using firebase ?**

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using [Ionic Native Push](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/native/push/). You can see there that it supports browser. You will need to create a certificate and a firebase app to configure and send push.

Maybe you could also check [this](https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/push-messages-with-firestore/) tutorial. It is for angular but for ionic it's similar.